# Docker not working after installation

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, failed-installation

I tried installing the docker using [the linux method](https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/).
However when the command `$docker run hello-world` is executed, it outputs:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What can be done about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure the daemon is running:

`$ps aux|grep "docker daemon"|grep -v "grep"`

#### A) The daemon is not launched (no lines are returned by the `ps`)

Start the daemon that is not working:

`$sudo /usr/bin/docker daemon -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

Or start it as a service with:

`$sudo /usr/sbin/service docker start`

At this point the daemon is launched.

#### B) The daemon is launched

As shown by the `ps` with something like:

`[..] /usr/bin/docker daemon -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

You're good to go with your first container with a:

`$sudo docker run hello-world`.

---

#### `sudo` and docker

If you want to use docker without being `sudo` (this you should, though you must be aware of the security warning!) a [good read of this will help you](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#create-a-docker-group).

Comment: I ran the above command to check whether daemon is running and got following result :    

root     12069  0.0  0.0  15948  2284 pts/0    R+   16:24   0:00 grep --color=auto docker daemon

Comment: That means your daemon is **not** running. Start it with `sudo service docker start`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this command as `sudo`.

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

This will give you enough privileges to perform that action.

If you want to enable your user to rung docker without sudo, then check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/477554/254014).